Proving that the dimension of the kernel of this map is $1$
Let $0 \neq z \in \mathbb{F}^n_2$, and define $A_z = \{ y\in \mathbb{F}^n_2 \mid z \cdot y = 0\}$, where $\,\cdot\,$ is the dot product
$$
z \cdot y = y_1 z_1 + \dots + y_n z_n \pmod 2.
$$
Suppose $m_1, \dots, m_k$ are generators of $A_z$.
Consider the map $f: \mathbb{F}^n_2 \to \mathbb{F}^k_2$ that maps
$$
x \mapsto (m_1 \cdot x, \dots, m_k \cdot x). 
$$
I want to show that the $\dim (\ker f) = 1$.
This is my attempt. I found that it must be the case that $k = n-1$ by constructing an appropriate basis. Thus, by the rank-nullity theorem it should be enough to show that $f$ is surjective. However,
I am stuck at this point.

I see no reason why the generators should be linearly independent, hence no reason why $k\geq n-1$ should be met with equality.  I think this is a duplicate to your earlier deleted problem, i.e. $x\mapsto \mathbf 0$ iff $x \perp A_z$ and your earlier problem was to show that was one dimensional [i.e. uniquely given by $z$, up to re-scaling]

As you guessed, $A_z$ is an hyperplane, hence of dimension $n-1$. Thus if $(m_1, \dots, m_k)$ generates $A_z$, $k \geqslant n-1$ and you can choose $n-1$ vectors of this family to form a basis of $A_z$.
For simplicity, suppose that $(m_1,\dots,m_{n-1})$ form a basis, then $x \cdot m_j$ for $j\geqslant n$ can linearly be computed by the data of the  $x \cdot m_i, \, i<n$, so you can factorise $f$ into $f = h\circ g$ with $g(x) = (x \cdot m_1,\dots,x\cdot m_{n-1})$, $g:\mathbb{F}_2^n \to \mathbb{F}_2^{n-1}$ and $h$ injective.
We can easily see (since $(m_1,\dots,m_{n-1})$ forms a basis of $A_z$) that $g_{| A_z}$ is an isomorphism, thus its rank is $n-1$, which means its kernel is of dimension $1$, but $\ker f = \ker h \circ g = \ker g$ since $h$ is injective. This gives us $\dim \ker f = 1$.
Another solution is to check out the matrix of this linear morphism:
$$f = \begin{pmatrix}
m_1^T \\
m_2^T\\
\vdots\\
m_k^T
\end{pmatrix}$$
So its rank is the same as
$$f = \begin{pmatrix}
m_1 &
m_2&
\cdots&
m_k
\end{pmatrix}$$
Which is equal to the dimension of $\operatorname{Span}(m_1,\dots,m_k) = A_z$, so its rank is $n-1$. You thus have
$$\dim \ker f + n-1 = n$$
thus $\dim \ker f = 1$

I used vertical writing for vectors, with left multiplication for matrices
